# Break python long into limbs

Tags: python, cryptography, gmp, gmpy

I'm trying to write an implementation of [Montgomery multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_reduction#Modular_multiplication) in Python and I need an equivalent to GMP's [`mpz_getlimbn()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Special-Functions.html) for Python longs but I can't for the life of me seem to find one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I've implemented the following but I get index out of range errors for limbs which don't occur in GMP.

```
def unpack(x, b):
    if gmpy2:
        return [long(x) for x in gmpy2.unpack(gmpy2.mpz(x), b)]

    b = 2 ** b
    r = []
    while x:
        x, temp = divmod(x, b)
        r.append(temp)
    return r
```

Comment: This is not part of the public API. See http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/db842f730432/Include/longintrepr.h for the implementation details you will have to reach into.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to dig into this without using Cython or is that the only route?

Comment: I don't know enough about Cython to know if it's an appropriate tool to use here. I was thinking in terms of writing C directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your `unpack()` and it appears to work for me. If you still get an error, please post the full error.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> 
>>> def unpack(x, b):
...     try:
...         return [x for x in gmpy2.unpack(gmpy2.mpz(x), b)]
...     except NameError:
...         b = 2 ** b
...         r = []
...         while x:
...             x, temp = divmod(x, b)
...             r.append(temp)
...         return r
... 
>>> unpack(123456**7, 15)
[mpz(0), mpz(0), mpz(4096), mpz(25855), mpz(24508), mpz(31925), mpz(15111), mpz(10775)]
>>> del(gmpy2)
>>> unpack(123456**7, 15)
[0, 0, 4096, 25855, 24508, 31925, 15111, 10775]
```

When using `gmpy2`, I left the results as `mpz` to show that `gmpy2` was used.

Python's long integer type uses limbs that store either 15 or 30 bits. `sys.int_info` will provide the specifics for your system.

BTW, I maintain `gmpy2` and it's nice to see someone use `unpack()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and thanks for the great library. In the docs for `mpz_getlimbn()` it states "The least significant limb is number 0" from what I can gather one must reverse the output of unpack to match this functionality right?

Comment: Actually cancel that my unit tests now seem to pass without the reversing of the output of unpack.